# show checkboxes based on values of previous fields checkboxes in django/js

Tags: javascript, html, django, checkbox

I have this dynamic loading problem in my django project for making a worksheet by the teacher.

**Problem**

I have classrooms which have Topics, and Topics have SubTopics. I have to create a dropdown for classroom where teacher can select one class. Based on the class I am showing Topics as checkboxes so that teacher can select various topics. I have solved the issue so far. Now based on the checked topics and selected class I want to show subtopics as checkboxes to teacher.

**filter.html**

```
<form method="post" id="questionForm" data-topics-url="{% url 'qapp:ajax_load_classroom_topics' %}" 
        data-subtopics-url="{url 'qapp:ajax_load_topics_subtopics'}" novalidate>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <table>
            {{form.as_table}}
        </table>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<script>
    $("#id_classroom").change(function() {
        var url = $('#questionForm').attr("data-topics-url");
        var classroomId = $(this).val();

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: {'classroom':classroomId},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response_data) {
                $("#id_topic").empty().append(response_data.topics.map((t1) => {
                    return $('<label><input type="checkbox" name="topics_all" value="' +t1.id+ '"/>' +t1.topic_name+'</label>');
                }));
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<script>
    $(".checkbox").change(function(){
        console.log($("#id_topic").val());
    }); // --> stuck here! how to dynamically show subtopics in checkboxes
</script>
```

**views.py** *for ajax_load_topics_subtopics url*

```
def topics_subtopics(request):
    classroom = request.GET.get('classroom')
    topics = request.GET.getlist('topics_all[]')
    temp_subtopics = SubTopic.objects.filter(classrooms__classroom=classroom).filter(topic__id__in=topics)
    subtopics = temp_subtopics.order_by('subtopic_name').values('subtopic_name', 'id')
    response_stopics = {}
    try:
        response_stopics['subtopics'] = list(subtopics)
    except:
        response_stopics['error'] = "No Subtopics available in this class and Topics"
    print(response_stopics)
    print('classroom', classroom)

    return JsonResponse(response_stopics)
```

I am using modelform. If you need more details do let me know.

I have searched for the similar issue but they are all solving the classroom-topics issue. Can any one help me out here?

EDIT: *my attempt for 2nd script*

```
<script>
    $('.checkbox').on('click', (function() {
        var url = $('#questionForm').attr("data-subtopics-url");
        var classroomId = $('#id_classroom').val();
        var topicsId = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url:url,
            data:{
                'classroom':classroomId,
                'topics_all':topicsId
            },
            success: function(response_stopics) {
                $("id_subtopic").empty().append(response_stopics.subtopics.map((st1) => {
                    return $('<div class="stopics"><label><input type="checkbox" name="subtopics_all" value="'+ st1.id+'"/>'+st1.subtopic_name+'</label>');
                }));
            }
        });
    }));
</script>
```

**forms.py**

```
class QuestionFilterForm(forms.ModelForm):

DIFFICULTY = (('l', 'Low'), ('m', 'Medium'), ('h', 'High'))
CLASSROOM = (('1','I'), ('2','II'), ('3','III'), ('4','IV'), ('5','V'))

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(QuestionFilterForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['classroom'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=self.CLASSROOM)
    self.fields['topic'] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Topic.objects.none(),
                                                        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple
                                                    )
    self.fields['difficulty'] = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=self.DIFFICULTY,
                                                        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
                                                        required=True
                                                    )
    self.fields['subtopic'] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=SubTopic.objects.none(),
                                                        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple
                                                    )

class Meta:
    model = Questions
    fields = ['classroom', 'topic', 'difficulty', 'subtopic']
```

Comment: What happens when you run the code? As opposed to what you want to happen?

Comment: the first script is running fine. in the second script its showing nothing.

Comment: I am also doubtful about which attribute should I use in the second script on which an event should happen. Should it be class or id or should I go like `$input[name="topics_all"]` ?

Comment: You need to send a 2nd AJAX request to the server and grab the list of subtopics based on the selected topics. What exactly is the issue with that? Where exactly are you stuck? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: So, in the views.py you can see that I am fetching the subtopics based on the classroom and topics list. Now I am stuck in writing the js function, how should I go about this?

Comment: It's similar to the `$.ajax` you already have. Try it. SO isn't a free coding school / service.

Comment: I have updated the code with my 2nd script, its not loading any subtopics in the browser. I am using `.checkbox` for event handling. is that the right choice or should I use the ids of every topics which I got in `.getlist()` method?

Comment: I assume you've checked you are pulling a correct subtopic list and it is simply not going into the form.  Without seeing the form I do not know which fields are available.  Does you modelform have a subtopic field?

Comment: yes, I have checked the subtopics in the django shell and it is giving me correct subtopics list as per my logic in the view. I am trying to solve it and I think My issue is narrowed down to sending the list of  topicsId which are checked, from jquery to my view.